# How to type Sinhala in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, input-language

I need to type my documents in Sinhala language using LibreOffice writer. Are there any software that will enable typing and reading in Sinhala language?

Comment: It might work to enable it system wide (you can use Keyboard > Settings > Input Sources on Gnome/Unity desktops - `ibus-setup` may work as well), this can make the interface and keyboard read sinhala. You may need to use `sudo apt-get install fonts-lklug-sinhala` to install fonts to read some characters.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type the below command

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib
```

Give root password when prompted.

Open dash and search for **Text Entry** and open it. You will get a window like the one below.

[image]

Click on the + button on the lower left side and start typing ***sinh...*** till you get the entries in the window below.

[image]

Select **Sinhala;Sinhalese(Wijesekara(m17n))(IBus)** and click the Add button on the bottom. Now you can see the selected one was added to the Input sources list. You can toggle those input methods from the menu bar icon or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space bar</kbd>

Now you can type Sinhala anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type in Sinhala ,download LibreOffice 5.4 version,install and open it.Select writer.select "ISKOLA POTHA" font.You can type all you want in Sinhala.If you don't have the fonts installed,you should first do so.Mine is an old xp machine but those who have later windows may download latest versions of LibreOffice.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explain how to get those fonts.